# PyQt4 Combobox Not Updating After Initial Selection

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, selection

Combobox dbSelection does not update to apply in code when selecting table names from sqlite to display in combobox tabSelection.

It also takes a significant number of seconds to load the directory dialog window once the button is clicked.

I would also like to ensure that all tables within a database are listed in the tabSelection combobox.

The code is as follows and is associated with a Qt Designer file:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import qcDbWidget2
import os
import sqlite3

class MainDialog(QWidget, qcDbWidget2.Ui_qcQueryWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.dbDirSelect, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getDirName)

    def getDirName(self):
        existDir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
        dbDir = str(existDir)
        self.dbDirDisplay.setText(dbDir)

        dbFileList = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dbDir):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.db'):
                    dbFileList.append(file)

        self.dbSelection.addItems(dbFileList)

        tableList = []
        self.dbSelection.update()

        dbName = str(self.dbSelection.currentText())
        dbPath = str(dbDir + '\\' + dbName)
        conn = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
        c = conn.cursor()

        res = c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
        self.tabSelection.clear()
        for name in res:
            tableList.append(name[0])
            print(name[0])
        for name in tableList:
           self.tabSelection.addItems(tableList)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: If you are using pyqt4 I recommend using the QtSql module, for example if you use a QTableView with QSqlTableModel, it will be loaded automatically without the need to write sql requests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to use [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html) instead of `QTableList`?
Qt uses MVC which methods are way faster than doing it by hand.

In this case, it's pretty simple.
You create a model:

```
my_model =  QStringListModel()
```

You can then save data to `my_model`:

```
my_list = ["toto", "tutu", "tata"]
my_model.setStringList(my_list)
```

Once you have a `QTableView`, you use it's method [setModel()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#setModel) to provide the model.

```
my_table_view.setModel(my_model)
```

Comment: I was attempting to create a list of tables from a sqlite database.

Comment: Yes, I assumed so. In that case just change in my snippet the value of `my_list` to the list of tables from your sqlite db. Did I miss something?

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot. I'll have to look into creating a view.